# SOAP XML parsing with simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, soap, simplexml, soap-client

I'm trying to parse a simple xml soap response with `simplexml_load_string` without success. I  have already tried a lot of ways that I found in other questions without success.

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:F2bCobrancaRetorno xmlns:m="http://www.f2b.com.br/soap/wsbilling.xsd">
      <sacado numero="0000000015">
        <nome>Pedro Fernandes Steimbruch</nome>
        <email>pedrofsteimbruch@gmail.com</email>
      </sacado>
      <cobranca nosso_numero="0004912903" numero="0004912903" taxa_registro="0.00">
        <nome>Pedro Fernandes Steimbruch</nome>
        <email>pedrofsteimbruch@gmail.com</email>
        <url>http://www.f2b.com.br/Billing?id=eq5GuK</url>
      </cobranca>
      <log>OK&#13;</log>
    </m:F2bCobrancaRetorno>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want to get log and url objects.

Comment: You only pasted in here some XML but have not shown your code what you've tried so far. -1 + CV

Answer (score 0):

You may be accounting for it, but that XML document uses name spaces. That is what the colon in the XML tag means. The URIs given in the document tell the parser, in theory, where to find the schema for elements in that namespace.  To do this with simpleXml you would need to parse the file to get the URI for that name space, or in this case simply hard code it, i.e. "http://www.f2b.com.br/soap/wsbilling.xsd". Then you pass the URI to the children() method of the SimpleXml Object.

In this example $document contains the SimpleXML object containing the SOAP data. $subDocument is a new SimpleXML document that contains the elements from document that are in the namespace "m".

```
   $subDocument = $document->children("http://www.f2b.com.br/soap/wsbilling.xsd");
   echo $subDocument->log;
```

Since there are two namespaces (SOAP_ENV and m), one nested inside the other, I don't know if you would have to access "SOAP-ENV" before you could access "m", or if you can jump straight to "m".

This page discusses it. http://www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/